# Get repository from commit in jgit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have a `RevCommit` ([api](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevCommit.html#getAuthorIdent%28%29)) object. I want to get the `Repository` ([api](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Repository.html)) object from it. My main goal is to get the `origin` url. So I planned to get Repository -> getConfig() -> -> load() -> getString().

How to get config object from RevCommit object?
Is this the correct way to get origin url from a commit?

I tried googling but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RevCommit` does not reference the repository it was loaded from. You'll have to track that in your application code.
If you have a list of known repositories, you could lookup (`repository.resolve( commit.name() )`) the commit. It feels a bit hacky though. And of course, you'll end up with multiple hits if there are multiple repositories with the same content.

Once you hold the repository in question you may use `repository.getConfig().getString()` to obtain the origins.

If you believe that RevComit should reference the repository it belongs to, you may want to open an [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JGit&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All) to discuss that with the JGit team.